# Уважаемые знатоки, помогите, пожалуйста. Не могу понять, стоит ли в моём случае ставить тире?

Tags: пунктуация

И, кажется, вроде бы всё хорошо - но это не так. (Я знаю, что это не БСП, но почему-то хочется поставить тире (т. к. вроде резкое противопоставление).)

Comment: Мне кажется, что и "кажется" и "вроде бы" вместе — это чересчур. Лучше оставить что-то одно. Ведь смысл и то и другое придаёт практически один и тот же.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но вы мне подскажите, правильно ли стоит тире в данном предложении ?

Comment: По вопросам тире я не очень уверенно себя чувствую. Хорошо, что Sharon уже ответила.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***И кажется, вроде бы всё хорошо, но это не так.***

Тире в таком предложении не ставится.

Пояснение

1) Тире — **неосновной знак для ССП**, для его постановки нужны основания: неожиданное присоединение, резкое противопоставление, разная структура и т.д.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135

К тому же, как видно из приведенных у Розенталя примеров, **тире обычно ставится перед союзом И** (приводится только один пример с союзом А).

2) **Почему хочется поставить тире?** Между частями предложения **противительные** отношения, при этом интонационно предложение делится **на две части**.  А такая интонация обычно соответствует постановке тире.

То есть интонационно ССП похоже на БСП, но при наличии противительного союза тире уже не требуется (противительные отношения обозначены союзом).